# Error in Insert method for Ordered ArrayList

Tags: c++, arrays

Hey i am making an Ordered ArrayList for C++ and one of functions used to insert a number and replace a space in the ArrayList with this number is not working.  Im getting an error message saying : Error C2065: index_undeclared identifier;

Here is my code:

### OrderedArray.cpp

```
#include"OrderedArray.h"//To allow the use of Array.h Header file.
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;// To allow the use of the standard library.

int main()//Main method for OrederedArray.cpp.
{
    //Creating an array with the Datatype in from the template.
    OrderedArray<int> intArray(10);
    //Filling the Array(intArray)with elements from 1-10.
    intArray[0] = 1;
    intArray[1] = 200;
    intArray[2] = 323;
    intArray[3] = 976;
    intArray[4] = 545;
    intArray[5] = 767;
    intArray[6] = 234;
    intArray[7] = 123;
    intArray[8] = 456;
    intArray[9] = 789;
    
    intArray.printArray();
    intArray.Remove(7);
    intArray.printArray();
    intArray.Insert(1232,1);
    intArray.printArray();



getchar();
getchar();
}
```

### OrderedArray.h

```
//Header file for OrderedArray.cpp.
#ifndef ORDEREDARRAY_H
#define ORDEREDARRAY_H
//Template for use with the Array's data type.
template<class Datatype>
//***************************************************************************************
class OrderedArray
{

private:
    
//Member Variables.
    int size;
    int grow_size;
    int num_elements;
    Datatype* m_array;
//***************************************************************************************


public:
//Constructor.
    OrderedArray( int p_size)
    {
        m_array = new Datatype[p_size];
        size = p_size;
    }
//***************************************************************************************




//Destructor.
    ~OrderedArray()
    {
        if( m_array!= 0 )
            delete[] m_array;
        m_array= 0;
    }
//***************************************************************************************

//Access Operator: Syntax to allow the use of editing.
    Datatype& operator[] ( int p_index)
    {
        return m_array[p_index];
    }
//***************************************************************************************

//Functions.
    void ArrayFunction( int* p_array)
    {
    p_array[0] = 10;
    }
//Print Function: To print out all elemenst in the Array.
    void printArray()
    {
        for(int i=0;i< size;i++)
        {
            cout << "Position: " <<m_array[i]<<endl;
        }


    }
//***************************************************************************************

//Resize Function: To resize the Array.
    void Resize( int p_size)
    {
        Datatype* newarray = new Datatype[p_size];
        if( newarray== 0 )
            return;
        int min;
        if( p_size< size)
            min = p_size;
        else
            min = size;
        int index;
        for( index = 0; index < min; index++ )
            newarray[index] = m_array[index];
        m_size= p_size;
        if( m_array!= 0 )
            delete[] m_array;
        m_array= newarray;
    }
//***************************************************************************************

//Remove Function: To remove an element in an Array.
    void Remove( int p_index)
    {
        int index;
        for( index = p_index+ 1; index < size; index++ )
            m_array[index -1] = m_array[index];
    }
//***************************************************************************************
    //Size Function: To get the size of the Array.
    int Size()
    {
        return size;
    }
//***************************************************************************************
//Insert Function: To insert an element into the array between points in the index.
    void Insert( Datatype p_item, int p_index)
    {
        for(int index = size-1; index > p_index; index—)
        m_array[index] = m_array[index -1];
        m_array[p_index] = p_item;
    }
//***************************************************************************************
//***************************************************************************************


};

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say this:

```
    void Insert( Datatype p_item, int p_index)
{
    for(int index = size-1; index > p_index; index-)
    m_array[index] = m_array[index -1];
    m_array[p_index] = p_item;
}
```

When it should be this:

```
void Insert( Datatype p_item, int p_index)
{
    for(int index = size-1; index > p_index; index--)
    m_array[index] = m_array[index -1];
    m_array[p_index] = p_item;
}
```

Notice the *index--* at the end of the *for* statement in the revised code snippet.